# What can I expect working with a recruiter who sends template messages without even including names?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, recruitment, linkedin

I recently received a message from a recruiter on Linkedin, that read something as follows:

> Hi,
>
> Our client in best-of-whatever-industry is looking to hire a Sr.
>   Software Developer for their headquarters in Some City, State. Your
>   profile seems to match very well so I was hoping to discuss the role.
>
> Regards, Some Name

This recruiter didn't even include my name (the slightest amount of effort), nor did they mention what the role entails at all, or how I might fit said role.

It doesn't look like spam based on the recruiter's profile/connections, but it also seems like they are making literally zero effort in trying to find candidates. I did check the company's website, however, and the role *might* be a good fit.

Is this likely to be an indicator for how the recruiter will handle future communications and if so are there any downsides to me engaging with them?

Comment: @downvoter(s) how can I improve the question?

Comment: Didn't DV, but you are asking a "should I.." question, which happens to be asking for a choice. Also, truly answering what you might expect might be too of a guess to my taste. Perhaps you can rephrase your question?

Comment: Upvoted simply to knock out the downvote, this is a legitimate question, and as with anything recuriting will have a lot of soft skills and opinion.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Just rephrased it, now it's not opinion-based. "What can I expect" might be more answerable than "should I yes/no". Let me know if I can improve it further.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice it's better now :) added some tags that can help

Comment: Annnddd... @closevoters, how is this off-topic as per the Help Center? At least write a comment so I can modify/improve the question.

Comment: just respond with "Hello recuiter. I would love a job as <<position you have>> please contact me at <<contact info>> so we can discuss further <<signature>>" see what happens

Comment: You know very well that you can not base an entire expectation set off of a single interaction over email.  All it shows is Outlook is more tricky than the recruiter was capable of sending form letters to his candidates.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings this was through LinkedIn, and absolutely first impressions matter and you can learn a lot about another person from this sort of interaction, so I really don’t understand your comment.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice How is getting through linked in different than email?

Comment: @SaggingRufus Maybe you can do template/form messages in LinkedIn, I don't know, I've never been on the recruiter's end of the stick. In any case, template messages or copy/pasting without bothering to fill in a name seems like a red flag to me, and probably means something to people who have more experience in dealing with recruiters than I do.

Comment: Looks like spam to me.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I've done a quick edit to your question to try and address any "off-topic" concerns, hopefully I haven't substantially altered your intent. If so feel free to revert or try an edit of your own.

Comment: I don't think this question has an answer. Unless someone is familiar with the exact recruiter you're coming into contact with here,or has a particularly accurate crystal ball, nobody can give you any indication of what will happen in your interaction with this recruiter, at least not in any way that is backed up.

Comment: They are on a fishing trip, looking to collect fresh CVs. I get those most day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dear Professional  (like this?)

My gut reaction is a qualified no.  This is likely somebody making close to minimum wage whose job it is to gather lists of prospective candidates based on search results that match only one or two keywords on your resume, then do a mail merge like functionality to blast out emails to thousands of people.   In other words, as you say zero effort.

If you reply to such an email, chances are there are ten of these people reporting up to an experienced recruiter, and then the experienced recruiter will reply to you if it's a match.

Also if you get such an email chances are you'll get others from multiple agencies about the same gig.

A yes answer would be if you're really desperate to get out of your current contract or have a hard end date and want to avoid unpaid bench time.

Experienced recruiters that don't have their own minions will only contact you if they've done their research and there is a high match between you and the job.

Hope this helps, or at least amused you.

Comment: @bharal good recruiters do, but their data-scrubbing minions probably don't.

Answer (score 3):

As a former recruiting minion, I can say that this is a low effort cold message.
If you're interested in the position, ask them for job details without giving them any. If they cooperate in their first reply and don't try to avoid your questions, they might have been lazy or ignorant (newbie) of the trade ethics, you might want to continue with them; otherwise just ignore them or tell them you're not interested.

Comment: Yup! Agencies like to trawl for fresh CVs. They also like to be able to tell clients, "we have X number of CVs in our database". I get these fishing trip invites almost daily and ignore them all.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to find if it is possible to apply for the position through another channel (as the best-of-whatever-industry company webpage).
If that is not possible, I would give a try to the recruiter, if I am truly interested on the position.

About what you can expect, it is hard to say. Maybe they are lazy recruiters but maybe they are just on a superficial scan for candidates before giving a personalized and good support to those who are interested. In any case it is not the best of the presentations, for sure.